# Quarkus dev mode start throws EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, quarkus

I can not start quarkus in dev mode using the "quarkus dev" command. Since I am not sure what has changed but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Longer version of the error is:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd05962778, pid=20072, tid=13304
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.6+9) (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, emulated-client, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3d2778]
```

a bit later:

```
---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -javaagent:C:\Users\XY\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.quarkus\quarkus-class-change-agent\3.0.3.Final\ab2ac5ecd6b39c764a70e61cbb4ccca7b6dd5084\quarkus-class-change-agent-3.0.3.Final.jar -Dquarkus-internal.serialized-app-model.path=C:\GitProjects\TechEvaluation\build\tmp\quarkusDev\quarkus-app-model.dat -Dquarkus-internal-test.serialized-app-model.path=C:\GitProjects\TechEvaluation\build\tmp\quarkusDev\quarkus-app-test-model.dat -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:5005,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager C:\GitProjects\TechEvaluation\build\tech-evaluation-dev.jar

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 8 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.3031)
Time: Thu Jun 22 11:53:41 2023 Mitteleurop�ische Sommerzeit elapsed time: 2.204859 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001ca4b23eaa0):  JavaThread "build-50" [_thread_in_vm, id=13304, stack(0x0000009d98c00000,0x0000009d98d00000)]

Stack: [0x0000009d98c00000,0x0000009d98d00000],  sp=0x0000009d98cfd5b0,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x3d2778]
C  [jansi.dll+0x104e]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.fusesource.jansi.internal.CLibrary.init()V+0
j  org.fusesource.jansi.internal.CLibrary.<clinit>()V+12
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.ansiStream(Z)Lorg/fusesource/jansi/AnsiPrintStream;+62
j  org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.initStreams()V+7
j  org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole.out()Lorg/fusesource/jansi/AnsiPrintStream;+0
j  org.aesh.readline.terminal.impl.WinSysTerminal.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ZLorg/aesh/terminal/Terminal$SignalHandler;)V+4
j  org.aesh.readline.terminal.impl.WinSysTerminal.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+6
j  org.aesh.readline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.createWindowsTerminal(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/aesh/terminal/Terminal;+15
j  org.aesh.readline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.build()Lorg/aesh/terminal/Terminal;+125
j  org.aesh.readline.tty.terminal.TerminalConnection.<init>(Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V+85
j  org.aesh.readline.tty.terminal.TerminalConnection.<init>(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V+14
j  io.quarkus.deployment.console.ConsoleHelper.installConsole(Lio/quarkus/deployment/dev/testing/TestConfig;Lio/quarkus/deployment/console/ConsoleConfig;Lio/quarkus/runtime/console/ConsoleRuntimeConfig;Lio/quarkus/runtime/logging/ConsoleConfig;Z)V+95
j  io.quarkus.deployment.console.ConsoleProcessor.setupConsole(Lio/quarkus/deployment/dev/testing/TestConfig;Lio/quarkus/deployment/annotations/BuildProducer;Lio/quarkus/deployment/builditem/LaunchModeBuildItem;Lio/quarkus/deployment/console/ConsoleConfig;)Lio/quarkus/deployment/console/ConsoleInstalledBuildItem;+101
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@17.0.6
j  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+133 java.base@17.0.6
J 805 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@17.0.6 (10 bytes) @ 0x000001ca38caaa84 [0x000001ca38caaa20+0x0000000000000064]
J 804 c1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@17.0.6 (65 bytes) @ 0x000001ca38caae8c [0x000001ca38caad60+0x000000000000012c]
j  io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(Lio/quarkus/builder/BuildContext;)V+265
j  io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run()V+70
j  io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext$$Lambda$252+0x0000000800de96b0.run()V+4
j  org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+1
j  org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run()V+67
j  org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run()V+33
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@17.0.6
j  org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run()V+12
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000
```

et cetera.

I am using quarkus 3.0.3.Final and gradle with java 17. Not sure how much info else would be helpful. Just let me know.

Thanks,
Ayume

Comment: seems like an issue in native code - i.e. you are loading some dll/so and it has caused the crash